# Microsoft .NET raw socket type of service field

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets

I'm currently working on a project in VisualBasic.NET and am working with raw sockets to build my packets to send over the socket. This is because I have to set the Type of service field in the IP packet's header, something not possible with Winsock in modern versions of Windows. I can't use Diffserv because the embedded device the application is talking to requires me to use the full TOS field.

The current code implementation is fairly simplistic and works perfectly well - but only in Windows 8. If the code is run on any other Windows OS (XP or 7), the TOS field is overwritten as 0 no matter what (it needs to be set to 2 for the device I'm working with).

I've looked all over the internet for hints about this and have found several registry changes (all of which I have tried to no avail) as well as group policy edits. Most of these are for enabling the ability to set the TOS field in Winsock, which only works on XP.

I'm led to believe that the issue is caused by some change in settings in the network layer of the Windows OS but it's difficult to pinpoint exactly what has changed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As an update, we've worked out that it's the Explicit Congestion Notification that gets zeroed out. When having tried a larger TOS value, the upper bits are set but the lower bits are cleared by Windows.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more investigation, we discovered several things.

- You can correctly set a TOS field in Windows 8 by making the following Registry change:

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\QoS]
  "Do not use NLA"="1"
- You can correctly set a TOS field using WinSock in XP by making the following Registry change:

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]
  "DisableUserTOSSetting"=dword:00000000
- You **cannot** change the TOS field in Windows 7 seemingly. We have tried several different variations of code and Windows 7 versions with no success.

I'm not 100% sure why the above statements are true, but they are what we have discovered over about a month of testing on various different machines and OS variants.